# vb.net Replace existing class with CodeDoms generated class

Tags: vb.net, codedom

I've class like this (it's just example)

```
class child
   inherits parent1
end class
```

and then at runtime i want change become like this

```
class child
   inherits grandfatherclass
end class
```

I've been trying with code like this, sadly it's still inherits from parent1

```
Dim onewclass As CodeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VB")
Dim objCompilerParameters As New CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
Dim classString as string = "class child" & vbnewline & _
                            "     inherits grandfatherclass" & vbnewline & _
                            "end class"
onewclass.CompileAssemblyFromSource(objCompilerParameters, classString)
```

Is it possible to replace existing class with CodeDom generated class...?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace existing class with CodeDom. Instead you can create a new derived class and if you want. You can further inherit it again to suit your need.